# Knowing debug details with Qt Creator

Tags: c++, qt, debugging

I have a bug in my Qt C++ program and the only information that gives me the debugger is: *Invalid parameter passed to C runtime function.*

I need to detect the exact location of this bug because my program is too big. Is there anyway to redirect errors and debugging details to a file or something?

Comment: Which operating system are you using? Doesn't the debugger show you the stacktrace at the point of the crash?

Comment: I'm using Windows 7 64 bit . no, i only get this : (Invalid parameter passed to C runtime function) or sometimes this (program exited with code 255)